# Django WSGI Error Saving Model Choice Field in Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mod-wsgi, django-3.0

This doesn't break the application or throw any errors in the Django admin, but I get the following line in my apache error log and am not sure why or if it even matters:

```
[Wed Aug 12 20:49:29.414991 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid XXXXX:tid XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] [remote XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX] OPTION1
[Wed Aug 12 20:49:51.635383 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid XXXXX:tid XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] [remote XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX] OPTION2
[Wed Aug 12 20:50:11.403505 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid XXXXX:tid XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] [remote XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX] OPTION1
```

`OPTION1` and `OPTION2` are entries in a Django model `CharField` populated from a `choices` tuple list coded directly into the `models.py` file. It doesn't appear to be affecting the application (i.e. it's not crashing, failing to save, or sending any other errors), but it is filling up my apache error logs. It only seems to happen on hard-coded `choice` fields, not when the dropdown menu choice in the admin is a foreign relation.

Here is an example of my model code:

```
CHOICE_TYPES = [
    ('OPTION1', 'option 1'),
    ('OPTION2', 'option 2')
]

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    ...
    type = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=CHOICE_TYPES, default="OPTION1")
    ...
```

I am using Python 3.6.9, Django 3.0.9, and Apache 2.4.29 with mod_wsgi 4.5.17 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You reused the built-in `type`. That might have some side-effects.

Comment: That's something I just noticed, too. I will try to change it and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: I changed the name of the model field to sample_type from just type and I still get the same exact error unfortunately. Good idea though.